# add the contents of 2 txt files together

Tags: php, file

I have this small piece of code on my website that i use to count downloads.
its pretty simple really,
counter.php sends the command and counter.txt is just a 1 line text file with a number that auto goes up every time the link is clicked.

My question is, is it possible to have 2 counter.txt files and add them to a third counter.txt file?  so it would look something like:
counter.txt + counter2.txt = counter3.txt ?

```
$counter = 'counter.txt'; 
$download = 'downloadurlhere';

$number = file_get_contents($counter); // read count file 
$number++; // increment count by 1 
$fh = fopen($counter, 'w'); // open count file for writing 
fwrite($fh, $number); // write new count to count file 
fclose($fh); // close count file 
header("Location: $download"); // get download
```

So essentially i want to offer 2 downloads
a light version and a full version

and then keep track of each download count separately.  but then also have a count for the total of both downloads.

oh and to make sure i include enough detail, on the download.php page i echo the counter.txt file with

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('counter.txt');?>
```

Comment: Sure. Just get the contents of both files, then write to a new file.

Comment: .. that does not help me because thats exactly what im asking how to do

Comment: have you tried  $first = file_get_contents('file1.txt') , $second = file_get_contents('file2.txt') and then $third = $first + $second;  file_put_contents("newfile.txt",$third);  ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the counters of two files should be easy. You just have to read each file and then the variables are added and written to third counter file or whatever you desire. An example:

```
<?php
$first=file_get_contents("counter1.txt");
$second=file_get_contents("counter2.txt");
$sum=$first+$second;
file_put_contents("counter3.txt",$sum);
?>
```

Comment: this approach is not concurrency-safe, if 2 or more people try to vote at the same time, the numbers won't be accurate, only 1 of them will actually count. use flock() with LOCK_EX to fix it.

Comment: seriously, if 10 people vote at the same time, this code will only count 1 of them, and you will have lost 9 votes. here is a safe version that will lose 0 votes: ```$lock1=fopen("counter1.txt","rb");$lock2=fopen("counter2.txt","rb");$lock2=fopen("counter3.txt","rb");flock($lock1,LOCK_EX);flock($lock2,LOCK_EX);flock($lock3,LOCK_EX);$first=file_get_contents("counter1.txt");$second=file_get_contents("counter2.txt");$sum=$first+$second;file_put_contents("counter3.txt",$sum);flock($lock1,LOCK_UN);flock($lock2,LOCK_UN);flock($lock3,LOCK_UN);fclose($lock1);fclose($lock2);fclose($lock3);
```

Comment: google `race condition` if you want to understand why

Answer (score 0):

So here was the end result, I had to swap around the txt files for counter.txt and urls but this worked perfectly...

```
$count = 'counterfull.txt';
$total = 'total.txt';
$download = 'URL';

$number1 = file_get_contents($count);
$number1++;
$fh = fopen($count, w);
fwrite($fh, $number1);
fclose($fh);
$number2 = file_get_contents($total);
$number2++;
$fh = fopen($total, w);
fwrite($fh, $number2);
fclose($fh);

header("Location: $download");
```

Comment: this approach is not concurrency-safe, if 2 or more people try to vote at the same time, the numbers won't be accurate, only 1 of them will actually count. use flock() with LOCK_EX to fix it.

Comment: seriously, if 10 people vote at the same time, this code will only count 1 of them, and you will have lost 9 votes. here is a safe version that will lose 0 votes: https://pastebin.com/raw/mj9j5tfV - google `thread safety` if you want to understand why.

Comment: err, i should have said `google race condition if you want to understand why`, your code has a race condition bug.